# can Regex .test() in JavaScript test the whole string?

Tags: javascript, regex, frontend

I have looked everywhere and everything seems to point that .test() is supposed to be able to test an entire string but I can't get it to work. I tried the following:

```
var exp = new RegExp("^([a-z])$");
console.log( exp.test('hello') );

console.log( /^([a-z0-9])$/.test('abc12') );
```

Both return false when it's supposed to be true;

here's a link to a demo:
http://jsbin.com/ibokem/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) match single characters. You need to [repeat](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) them:

```
var exp = new RegExp("^([a-z]*)$");
console.log( exp.test('hello') );

console.log( /^([a-z0-9]*)$/.test('abc12') );
```

Or if you want to require at least one character, use `+` instead of `*`.

Also, if you're just using the patterns with `test`, you can get rid of the parentheses:

```
var exp = new RegExp("^[a-z]*$");
console.log( exp.test('hello') );

console.log( /^[a-z0-9]*$/.test('abc12') );
```

Comment: Don't know if `*` will be the right result, `+` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Niels I mention that after the first snippet.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed that.